# Special characters like â€˜ on view laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, special-characters

I am rendering articles from database. But it shows special characters on page.

```
ex. â€˜MINORITYâ€™ CAN SHOW THE â€˜MAJORITYâ€™ WHO IS IN CHARGE!
```

I am using laravel 5.2 and mysql. How can I avoid this ? I have used following in , But it doesn't resolved problem.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

Also tried, echo $newtitle = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Please help!

Comment: what is the encoding of your database ?

Comment: default_character_set_name = latin1 from db.

Comment: is it possible to convert it to UTF-8 ? I think that's the cause of the issue. Maybe do a backup before try it.

Comment: updated default_character_set_name=utf8. Still having issue

Comment: You should set every table to utf8.